# Ubuntu won't recognize any of my USB devices. Why?

Tags: linux, ubuntu-12.04

Currently using Ubuntu on my Sony Vaio laptop. Building a simple and fast machine for my father. But USB devices don't work. Mouses, pens or anything else.

When I run `lsusb` all seems ok, but Ubuntu just ignores everything I connect.

```
:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 054c:0281 Sony Corp. 
Bus 007 Device 002: ID 044e:300d Alps Electric Co., Ltd Bluetooth Controller (ALPS/UGPZ6)
```